# Use of inductors vs resistors

Tags: resistance, inductance

Why would we place an inductor in series with a lamp, rather than just a resistor? I'm sort of thinking it has something to do with being able to control voltage to the lamp, without effecting current? But I'm unsure.

Comment: I'm assuming Lamp is british for LED? Or do you mean an incandescent filament light bulb?

Comment: What is the context of the inductor and lamp circuit? What kind of lamp? Arc discharge lamps such as florescent,  mercury vapor, high pressure sodium etc with use ballasts, which are primarily an inductor to control the power consumed by the bulb.

Comment: @passerby a light bulb, yes.

Comment: We're drawing phasor diagrams, and needed to use Pythagoras theorem to find out what resistance and reactance our choke needed to be before the lamp, in order to have our supply voltage meet the rated voltage for the lamp

Answer (score 2):

With a resistor is the current in phase with the voltage so the power = voltage * current

With an inductor the current is 90° out of phase with the voltage
so you'll get something like this:[image]

Because an inductor doesn't want any current change the inductor will work against it.
So the current makes a 90° phase shift. in that way if you look at the current voltage plot
you can also have a positive current with a negative voltage this means you have a

negative power consumption = power generation
 so the power = voltage * current * cos(alpha)

in that way the inductors reactance (=2*pi*L*f) also has a resistance to limit the current but with that advantage it won't use any power in contrast with a resistor.

Comment: You're welcome!
Is this question answered or do you need any more explanation?

Comment: @Daniel Smith If the post answered your question,then you should click on the "accepted" button near the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reactive part of the inductor's impedance will allow the voltage across the lamp/current through the lamp to be set without the inductance itself consuming the power a pure resistance   in series with the lamp would.

Comment: Can you elaborate at all, to help me understand how this happens?